# Airplane carry-on allowance and plastic bags

Tags: air-travel, hand-luggage

I see some people coming to airplanes with lot of plastic bags, often containing something bought from airport shops. Don't these count towards carry-on baggage allowance? Could I bring more carry-on stuff from home by using plastic bags?

Comment: Couple of first answers implicate the possible role of security checkpoints here. I made another question for that part separately: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/20886/airport-security-checkpoint-controlling-carry-on-luggage-amount

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the airline.

Jet Blue makes no mention of airport shop items in [their carry-on policy](http://help.jetblue.com/SRVS/CGI-BIN/webisapi.dll/,/?St=115,E=0000000000123980807,K=6820,Sxi=17,case=obj%28633%29), but the [United Airlines policy](http://www.united.com/cms/en-us/travel/pages/baggagecarry-on.aspx) states that "a limited amount of duty-free merchandise or food purchased in the airport" doesn't count against the carry-on limit and the [Delta policy](http://www.delta.com/content/www/en_US/traveling-with-us/baggage/during-your-trip/carry-on.html) doesn't count "food or drink purchased after clearing the security checkpoint."

Carry-on items from home would count against the carry-on limit in these situations.